# Multi color progress bar with border-radius and different border color

Tags: css, less

I am trying to create this progress bar, but struggle since it has border-radius AND a different border color for each sub-progress element.

Anyone has any idea how this can be implemented?
[image]

This is what I achieved so far, which doesn't include border:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anatel/pen/GRZGjBQ)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 24px;
  width: 280px;
  background: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress-bar-fill-1 {
  width: 30%;
  background: #F16172;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.progress-bar-fill-2 {
  width: 20%;
  background: #31C4F3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-bar-fill-1"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar-fill-2"></div>
</div>
```

If I try to add a border to `.progress-bar-fill-1` for example, It doesn't appear on the corners.
[image]

**Notice that I don't know the percentage values in advance, so I can't solve the problem by adding `border-radius` to the first progress element.**

Thanks

Comment: Could you share your html code ? I don't make sense.

Comment: @MaximJin I added the code in which I am stuck at... don't know how to add borders to each element.

Comment: you added overflow hidden in parent element. if you only add the border in the first element, .progress-bar-fill-1 { border-radius: 16px; }

Comment: Yes, I mentioned in the question that it will only help for this example, but it's not generic enough... I need to find a css solution for every case.

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 24px;
  width: 280px;
  background: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.progress-bar-fill-1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progress-bar-fill-1:before {
  position: absolute;  
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: "";
  background: #F16172;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.progress-bar-fill-2 {
  width: 20%;
  position:relative;  
}

.progress-bar-fill-2:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -16px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  background: #31C4F3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
```

please check the result.
you used the flex. so we can not add the margin to the second div.

Comment: Thanks, but it has round corners in each sub-progress element, and I need it like in the design. and to be generic as I don't know exactly how many sub-progresses it will contain and in what width.

Answer (score 1):

with clip-path, pseudo element and some CSS variables you can easily do this using one element. The trick is to have 3 elements on the top of each other (the main element and 2 pseudo element) then you cut the pseudo element to show only the needed part:

```css
.progress-bar {
  --b:2px; /* boder width */
  --s:2px; /* space between progress */

  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  margin:5px;
  background: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position:relative;
  border:var(--b) solid grey;
  position:relative;
}
.progress-bar::before,
.progress-bar::after{
  content:"";
  border-radius:inherit;
  border:inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(-1*var(--b));
  left:calc(-1*var(--b));
  bottom:calc(-1*var(--b));
  right:calc(-1*var(--b));
}

.progress-bar::before {
  background: #F16172;
  border-color:red;
  clip-path:inset(0 calc(100% - var(--f1)) 0 0);
}

.progress-bar::after {
  background: #31C4F3;
  border-color:blue;
  clip-path:inset(0 calc(100% - var(--f1) - var(--f2)) 0 calc(var(--f1) + var(--s)));
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar" style="--f1:30%;--f2:20%;"></div>

<div class="progress-bar" style="--f1:50%;--f2:20%;--b:3px;"></div>

<div class="progress-bar" style="--f1:60%;--f2:10%;--s:5px"></div>

<div class="progress-bar" style="--f1:20%;--f2:70%;--b:1px"></div>

<div class="progress-bar" style="--f1:20%;--f2:80%;--s:10px"></div>
```

Comment: Nice! I only worry about browser support.
And also, can this be animated somehow with slide in?

Comment: @AnatEliahu what kind of animation?

Comment: @AnatEliahu like this: https://jsfiddle.net/suc4b1jz/ ? hover to see the effect

Answer (score 0):

## Why this problem occurs:

The parent-element uses `overflow: hidden;` and `border-radius: 16px;`. What results in a parent-element with rounded corners and everything within is masked to the parent-element.

Because the child-element (aka `.progress-bar-fill-1`) is originally a square, will result in squared borders also. But the front/beginning of the child-element will be masked by its parent-element with overflow.

The solution for this is, to also round the first child-element within the masked parent-element, like described below.

## Solution:

You have to add also a border-radius to the first child-element. Aka `border-radius: 0 0 16px 16px 0;` to `.progress-bar-fill-1`, like the example below.

## Fixed code sample:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 24px;
  width: 280px;
  background: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress-bar-fill-1 {
  width: 30%;
  background: #F16172;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 0 0 16px 16px 0;
}

.progress-bar-fill-2 {
  width: 20%;
  background: #31C4F3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-bar-fill-1"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar-fill-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is still a problem if I want a more generic solution, see my new comment to the post with example.

Comment: Can you maybe explain why you want to add borders to the child-elements? Instead of the parent-element?

Comment: only because each child element has a different color, if you have any idea of how to have multiple colors for the border it's also good.
I also thought of having 2 progress bars one on top of each other (absolute position) and somehow use it as a trick.

Answer (score 0):

If I add this to `.progress-bar-fill-1`:

```css
border-top-left-radius: 16px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
```

It still doesn't solve the problem for example in this case, when `.progress-bar-fill-1` is very small, then `.progress-bar-fill-2`'s border will have the same problem.. so I need a more generic solution as I need to create a React component out of it.

Here is the problem:
[image]

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 24px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress-bar-fill-1 {
  width: 1%;
  background: #F16172;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 16px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
}

.progress-bar-fill-2 {
  width: 20%;
  background: #31C4F3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-bar-fill-1"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar-fill-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code a bit.
It won't look good on 1%, but 2% and so on looks just like the design.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 24px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress-bar-fill-1 {
  width: 2%;
  background: #F16172;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-top-left-radius: 16px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
}

.progress-bar-fill-2 {
  width: 20%;
  background: #31C4F3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-bar-fill-1"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar-fill-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution that also supports IE11 (sort of) and includes slide in animation:
https://jsfiddle.net/5kphcLqg/

```css
@keyframes slideInFill {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  } 

  99% {
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  }

  100% {
        border-top-right-radius: 16px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
  }
}

@keyframes slideInBorder {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}
 
.container { 
  position: relative;
}

.borders {
  height: 24px;
  width: 280px;
  background: #DCDFDF;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.borders-fill-1 {  
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  background: #06A2D4;
}

.animate {
  height: 24px;
  top: 0;   
  animation: slideInBorder 1s ease-in forwards;  
}

.borders-fill-1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9
}

.borders-fill-2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background: white; 
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9
}

.borders-fill-2 {
  width: 78%;
  background: #D31A47;  
  position: relative;
}

.fill-bg {
  background: #eaeaea;
  width: 280px;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  padding: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.filling-wrapper {
  border-radius: 16px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 1px solid #D31A47;
}

.filling {
  width: 280px;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,      
    #31C4F3 20%,
    #F16172 20%,
    #F16172 98%,
    transparent 98%
  );
  animation: slideInFill 1s ease-in forwards; 
  border-top-left-radius: 16px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
  padding: 1px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="borders">
        <div class="borders-fill-1 animate"></div>
        <div class="borders-fill-2 animate"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fill-bg"></div>
    <div class="filling">
    </div>
</div>
```